# Why is date() returning an unexpected value?

Tags: php, date, datetime, foreach

Here's a `var_dump` of an array called `$events`:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'weekday' => string '0' (length=1)
      'start_time' => string '2013-12-09 12:00:00' (length=19)
      'name' => string 'Lunch' (length=5)
      'location' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'weekday' => string '0' (length=1)
      'start_time' => string '2013-12-09 17:00:00' (length=19)
      'name' => string 'Dinner' (length=6)
      'location' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'weekday' => string '1' (length=1)
      'start_time' => string '2013-12-09 08:00:00' (length=19)
      'name' => string 'Breakfast' (length=9)
      'location' => string '2' (length=1)
```

When I run the following:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo $event['start_time'] . ', ' . date('g:i a', $event['start_time']);
}
```

here's what I get:

```
2013-12-09 12:00:00, 4:33pm
2013-12-09 17:00:00, 4:33pm
2013-12-09 08:00:00, 4:33pm
```

I would expect:

```
2013-12-09 12:00:00, 12:00pm
2013-12-09 17:00:00, 5:00pm
2013-12-09 08:00:00, 8:00am
```

Why is every call to `date()` returning the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `date()` is supposed to be a numeric timestamp. Instead, you're giving it a whole date, which it is trying to parse as a number. From that it gets 2013 seconds which is 33 minutes & 33 seconds. In a UTC-8 time zone that comes out as 33 minutes after 4pm the previous day... Basically it results in nonsense.

Try using `strtotime` on the string:

```
echo $event['start_time'] . ', ' . date('g:i a', strtotime($event['start_time']));
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining where the `4:33pm` value was coming from.  Remember kids, mySQL timestamp != UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

Need the date that is put into date() function to be unix timestamp.

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo $event['start_time'] . ', ' . date('g:i a', strtotime($event['start_time']));
}
```